# Angularjs cascade dropdown with json object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

i'm trying to understand how controllers works in angularjs using cascade dropdowns. But my second dropdown is not being populated based on the previous dropdown value.

My JSON arry result:

```
[{
    "id": "23031",
    "fabricante": "ALFA ROMEO",
    "modelo": "33",
    "motor": "1.3 \/ 1.3 ie",
    "combustivel": "Gasolina \/ GNV",
    "ano_vela": "",
    "ngk": "",
    "ngk_green": "BPR6EY",
    "gap": "0,7",
    "ano_cabo": "",
    "cabos_ngk": "",
    "inicio": "",
    "fim": "",
    "seguimento": "4 RODAS",
    "ano_bobina": "",
    "bobina_ngk": "",
    "pais": "Argentina",
    "n_processo": "0"
}, {
    "id": "23057",
    "fabricante": "ARO",
    "modelo": "Serie 10",
    "motor": "1.4",
    "combustivel": "Gasolina \/ GNV",
    "ano_vela": "",
    "ngk": "BP6HS",
    "ngk_green": "",
    "gap": "0,7",
    "ano_cabo": "",
    "cabos_ngk": "",
    "inicio": "",
    "fim": "",
    "seguimento": "4 RODAS",
    "ano_bobina": "",
    "bobina_ngk": "",
    "pais": "Argentina",
    "n_processo": "0"
}]
```

My Controller **EDITED**:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('fabricanteController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('JSON_PATH').success(function (data) {
    $scope.fabricantes = data;
    $scope.$watch('fabricante', function(newVal) {
    if (newVal) $scope.modelo = data;
    console.log($scope.modelo);
});
});
}]);
```

And my HTML:

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
    <div class="input-label">
        Fabricante
    </div>
    <select ng-model="fabricante" ng-options="fab.fabricante for fab in fabricantes track by fab.fabricante">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled">Selecionar</option>
    </select>
</label>

<label class="item item-input item-select">
    <div class="input-label">
        Modelo
    </div>
    <select ng-model="modelo" ng-options="mod.modelo for mod in fabricantes">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled">Selecionar</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

Tried to look around how to make it work but no luck.
Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried to apply this after the bind on watch? $scope.$apply()

Comment: @felipekm, yes it throws an error: Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

Comment: could you place all your controller code?

Comment: @felipekm, edited the controller part on question, thanks for helping

Comment: What you wanna print on the second DDL? I'm a bit confused about it, eg: When you select Alfa Romeu what do you wanna show?

Comment: The first is the Car Brand, then based on this first selection, i want to print on second select options the Car Models based on the Car Brand selected.

Comment: Yeah ok, but your 'modelo' field isn't an array right? will you only show one option?

Comment: No, i'll display all the options based on the first selection, do i need a second object array then?

Comment: Absolutelly If you can have more "modelos" options.

Comment: This is what i'm trying to do : http://jsfiddle.net/annavester/Zd6uX/

Comment: How about that below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna show the `'modelo'` property of the selected `'fabricante'` object you must point the `ng-option` of your second DDL to a new `$scope` array variable such:

```
$scope.modelos = [{"modelo": newVal.modelo}];
```

Your ng-options should be:

```
<select ng-model="test" ng-options="mod.modelo for mod in modelos">
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/17833/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, as i'm returning the data as the json above, how could i write to get the `[{"modelo: newVal.modelo"}]`? Something like this? `$scope.modelos = newVal.data.modelo`?

Comment: Yes, but attempt what you are referring on ng-options, above we're accessing mod.modelo so you must have this property "modelo" on "modelos" $scope variable.

Comment: Sorry mate, have been busy a lot and forgot to mark as accepted answer, it worked great for me here. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your watch isn't firing because you're passing in a string, not a variable. Also, I don't know where you're checking newVal, but it won't work like that..

Basic implementation:

```
$scope.$watch($scope.fabricante, function() {
    $scope.modelo = data;
    console.log($scope.modelo);
});
```

With newVal checking:

```
$scope.$watch($scope.fabricante, function() {
    if($scope.modelo!=data)
    {
      $scope.modelo = data;
      console.log($scope.modelo);
    }

});
```

You can also use ng-change on the Select box, which will fire on any change.

```
<select ng-model="fabricante" ng-change="doSomething()" ng-options="fab.id for fab in fabricantes"></select>
```

Comment: @Cris Lonardo, I tried your suggestion but the second dropdown is not changing the options based on the first selection.

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to link the two boxes together, but to be clear, a watcher works with an expression that can be a function or a string. If you want to watch an object, you should use a function. Here's an example of linking a select to the output of another, as well as changing it with a watcher: http://plnkr.co/edit/U3O1FjsPNmwdMYZ6nfxy?p=preview